# Grab part of url with chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've been playing with chrome extensions. However, I'm not certain which function to call to grab part of a URL and fit it into another URL, then save it in the browser storage.

Problem: need to grab `123-event-id` from [https://ab.website/`123-event-id`](https://ab.website/%60123-event-id%60) and a button trigger to save it as https:// portal.website/events/`123-event-id`/summary with an option (button) to delete later.

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the URL of the active tab

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
  let url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

You can use localStorage or chrome.storage to store data.